# Talk to all instances of Content Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with a Content Script and Popup Script. In the popup I have a settings page that changes certain variables on the Content Script by talking to it using [chrome messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). The content script runs on all YouTube sites. If there are multiple instances of YouTube/the content script, in the popup it will only change the setting/value on the currently viewed page. Is there any way to talk to all of the instances of the content script across all pages? Currently I'm using [localstorage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) as a workaround so when the user sets a value/setting on one it will set it on the other when the page is refreshed or there is a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) to get all tabs with specific properties, then do message passing to each of them.

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
       if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
         // handle errors like access issues
       } else {
         // Do message passing here
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Advice: also evaluate `chrome.runtime.lastError` in this callback to silence denied access errors.

Comment: @Xan, so when will the access errors be brought out? When the author doesn't include the sites url in manifest?

Comment: Or it's a tab you can't gain access to. Or a frame.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your settings using [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), your content script can:

1. Access it directly without Messaging
2. Detect changes by hooking into `chrome.storage.onChanged` and react accordingly.

That's probably the "least messy" solution.